# What is the best way to determine if a file exists within a directory?

Tags: linux, bash

I am looking for an efficient way to check that a file exists within a directory. I came across this line of code while I was doing an internet search. It looks like a test is being run on the home directory.

```
if test -e $HOME$; then echo $HOME$; fi
done
```

What does it mean if the test command is run with the home directory as a parameter? Is this an efficient way to test that a file exists?

I tried to execute the code and the test was successful. But I don't understand why the test was successful.

Comment: Why are you putting `$` after the variable?

Comment: What is `done` for? That only belongs at the end of a `for` or `while` loop, not after `if`.

Comment: If you want to test if a file exists, you need to put the filename after the directory, e.g. `if test -e "$HOME/$file"`

Comment: `test -e $HOME` just tells you if the home directory exists, not a file in it. Since the directory does exist, the test was successful.

Comment: Is there a typo bring/being?

Comment: `-e` tests for any directory entry. If you are only interested in plain files, use `-f`. See _man test_ for details. Of course `$HOME$` does not make sense in your code. It would be expanded to your homedirectory, followed by a `$`.

Comment: Can you provide he URL where you found this code? It shouldn't do anything useful if you copied it correctly.

Comment: Note: there are limitations to what `-e` matches, and options like `-s` (exists and non-empty), `-f` (file exists and is regular file) `-h` (file exists and is symlink), etc.. See `man 1 bash` under CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS.

Comment: BTW, the sole `done` in your code also does not make sense.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to provide the link to where you found that piece of code so we can understand it's context and why you thought it'd be the right approach plus we may be able to help whoever posted it.

Answer (score 0):

test is a command for your purpose, but you are using Linux and the ways to determine if a file exists are huge (even you could develop specific programs for that).

From man:

```
TEST(1)                                                            User Commands                                                            TEST(1)

NAME
       test - check file types and compare values

SYNOPSIS
       test EXPRESSION
       test
       [ EXPRESSION ]
       [ ]
       [ OPTION
...
       -e FILE
              FILE exists
...
```

Regarding to your last question, test will verify if $HOME exists; and if exist it will print $HOME

Answer (score 0):

If you know the files you want to check, you can use a conditional like so :

- `-e` : check whether the file exists

```
    if [[ -e /path/to/file ]]
    then
      echo "exist"
    else
      echo "does not exist"
    fi
```

If you just want to check if a directory is empty or not you can try :

- `-I` : avoid listing dots
- `-n`: check if $var is empty or not

```
    var=$(ls -a -I . -I .. /dir/)
    if [[ -n $var ]]
    then
      echo "dir is not empty"
    else
      echo "dir is empty"
    fi
```

Answer (score 0):

```bash
FILE='some_file_to_check'
[ -f "${FILE}" ] && echo "File ${FILE} exists."
```

Oneliner:

```bash
FILE='some_file_to_check'; [ -f "${FILE}" ] && echo "File ${FILE} exists."
```